# Does NSString Support Non-Standard/Non-English characters?

Tags: cocoa, localization, nsstring

I am using an xml parser to populate an array. This string: 'Calle Mare de Déu de' generates an exception at `[NSPlaceholderString initwithstring:]`. On Snow Leopard (10.6) it reports a nil argument while on Leopard (10.5) it throws an exception but reports no error.

When I replace the string 'Calle Mare de Déu de' with 'Calle Mare de Deu de' then it works fine. The problem is caused by the 'é' character.

Does NSString not support this and other special characters?

Thanks
Deepika

Comment: This question is very hard to understand, can you try to clarify it further please?

Comment: The main problem is clear enough (I think the questioner is pushing the limits of his/her command of English), but there are some details I'm wondering about, such as (1) whether “Calle Mare de Déu de” is coming from a database or an XML parser, (2) what API the questioner is using, and (3) what “convert[ing] it into Array” means.

Answer (score 3):

> exception occur NSPlaceholderString initwithstring:] nil argument on snow leapord and on leapord exception occur but alert does not come.

You get an exception telling you you passed a `nil` argument because you passed a `nil` argument.

The string you passed there was `nil`. This has nothing to do with the encoding of the string, for two reasons:

1. There is no string. (If you had passed a string, you would not have passed `nil`.)
2. Strings do not have encoding; they are simply character strings. Encodings get you from human-language characters (in strings) to sequences of bytes (in data).

Moreover, if you had a string to pass to `initWithString:`, you would not need to create a string using `initWithString:`, because you already have the string. If you wanted to copy it, you could simply send it a `copy` message.

We don't know what you do already have, which is vitally important. Please edit your question to include the code that gets the “string” out of the database or from the XML parser and passes it to `initWithString:`.

> Is It only due to 'é', means I want to know if NSString does not supported 'é' or any other characters

NSString supports all of the characters in Unicode. To a practical extent, this means all of them.